# SalesLogix Null Values

Tags: saleslogix

I am working on `SalesLogix 7.5 C#`.

I have an aspx page which has a text-box as a control which is a mandatory field. When i enter some data and save, it is saved. Now, when i edit that record and make that text-box as blank it gives me an Error Message saying that this is a mandatory field please enter some value.

Now when I enter the same value as it was before editing, it still shows me the text-box as blank.

Example:

1. I put "James" in the textbox and save.
2. On editing: i made it blank (recieved an error message).
3. Again I entered : "James" (Got the same Error Message)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, unable to add a comment to the original question but need some more information.

Are you doing this via App Architect or in ASP.NET outside of SalesLogix?
Are you doing this as a QuickForm or a custom SmartPart?
Can you provide the  tag for the field that isn't working and the relevant lines from the OnAddEntityBindings function in the .aspx.cs?
Have you stepped-through via the Visual Studio Debugger your btnSave_Click code to check it's saving correctly?